# Asignar valores a respuesta JSON según condiciones

Tags: javascript, json, objeto, algoritmos

espero se encuentren bien. He estado trabajando con una API externa en NodeJS y necesito modificar su respuesta bajo ciertas condiciones.

---

### El problema

Esta matriz de 8x6 representa los asientos disponibles de las butacas de una sala de cine.

```
const availableSeats = [
     5,   6,   7,        9,  10,  11,  12,
         34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,
    57,  58,       60,  61,  62,  63,  64, 
    81,  82,  83,  84,       86,  87,  88,
   109,      111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
   137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144
]
```

Y estos son (algunos) de los asistentes a la sala:

```
"customers": [
      {
        "age": 73,
        "purchase_id": 6,
        "ticket": 10,
        "seat_id": null
      },
      {
        "age": 28,
        "purchase_id": 6,
        "ticket": 11,
        "seat_id": null
      },
      {
        "age": 34,
        "purchase_id": 7,
        "ticket": 12,
        "seat_id": null
      },
      {
        "age": 8,
        "purchase_id": 7,
        "ticket": 13,
        "seat_id": null
      },
      {
        "age": 21,
        "purchase_id": 8,
        "ticket": 14,
        "seat_id": null
      },
```

Debo asignar la llave "seat_id" a cada asistente siguiendo estas reglas:

- Los menores de edad deben sentarse al lado y en la misma columna que su tutor
- La llave "purchase_id" indica que en una compra se compraron varios "tickets". Los asientos deben asignarse siguiendo la regla de que cada ticket debe estar lo más cercano posible, sea en la misma columna o fila.

---

### Resultado esperado

- Para menores de edad, es válida una distribución tal que:

(Mismo valor purcharse_id, así que los asientos deben estar en la misma columna, como por ejemplo, seat_id: 57 y seat_id: 81)

```
"customers": [
      {
        "age": 34,
        "purchase_id": 7,
        "ticket": 12,
        "seat_id": 57
      },
      {
        "age": 8,
        "purchase_id": 7,
        "ticket": 13,
        "seat_id": 81
      }
```

- Para el resto, son válidas las siguientes opciones:
  (Por ejemplo, seat_id: 9 y seat_id: 10], tienen el mismo valor de purchase_id, y pueden estar en la misma fila o columna)

```
"customers": [
      {
        "age": 73,
        "purchase_id": 6,
        "ticket": 10,
        "seat_id": 7
      },
      {
        "age": 28,
        "purchase_id": 6,
        "ticket": 11,
        "seat_id": 8
      },
      {
        "age": 21,
        "purchase_id": 8,
        "ticket": 14,
        "seat_id": 144
      },
]
```

Espero puedan darme orientación al respecto, o, si es posible, ayuda en la codificación (como que métodos utilizar). Estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Por favor lee: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Debes hacer una pregunta especifica, ademas debemos ver en tu pregunta un esfuerzo por lograr lo que deseas, si solo pones el enunciado y esperas que te digan que hacer estas en el lugar equivocado.

Comment: Muestras el codigo del enunciado. Pero no de ningun intento de resolución. Que has conseguido hasta ahora y donde te está atascando ? Se ve interesante el problema. ¿ que tal lo llevas ? Edita la pregunta añadiendo debajo lo que vas consiguiendo y donde te atastas. Un saludo. Falta saber tambien si "curstomers" llenan el teatro o quedan asientos vacios? Un saludo.